# Show popup when user tries to exit the browser (GMail style)

Tags: javascript, browser

I have to prompt a user when he/she tries to exit the browser window. For example, when you go to GMail and you start composing a new message, and then try to close it before saving anything, GMail will give you a popup saying something like:

> Do you really want to exit this page?

and then you have a choice of either leaving the page or staying on it. So what I am interested in is how they did it and what trick they used (if any) when the user presses `Stay on this page`.

Comment: I just want to say, this can be annoying for some users. Do you *really* need it? Couldn't you save the info (somewhere), without having to do this?

Comment: Please don't do this. Signed, all internet users.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid annoying users, you would probably want to have the state to be changeable, depending on if an operation is running. Something like this:

```
window.beforeunload = function(){
  if(isPerformingOperation) {
    return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
  }
}
```

Set `isPerformingOperation` to true when you want to prompt them, and turn it off when you are done.

Answer (score 4):

Bind a function to [`onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
};
```

Should work in all browsers (tested in IE 8, FF 3.6, Chrome 9).

Or with jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
  return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```